# Google analytics mailto tracking

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I've been working with this google analytics code to track mailto links and it simply is not working. I feel like it is something simple(a bracket missing somewhere or something), but I have tried several things and just can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').mouseup(function(){
        href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href !== null) {            
            href_lower = href.toLowerCase();
            if(href_lower.substr(-3) == "pdf" || href_lower.substr(-3) == "xls" || href_lower.substr(-3) == "doc" ||
               href_lower.substr(-3) == "mp3" || href_lower.substr(-3) == "mp4" || href_lower.substr(-3) == "flv" ||
               href_lower.substr(-3) == "txt" || href_lower.substr(-3) == "csv" || href_lower.substr(-3) == "zip") {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', href_lower.substr(-3), href]);
            }
        }
        else if (href_lower.substr(0, 4) == "http") {
            var domain = document.domain.replace("www.",'');
                if(href_lower.indexOf(domain) == -1){
                    href = href.replace("http://",'');
                    href = href.replace("https://",'');
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound Traffic', href]);
                }  else if (href && href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
                    jQuery(this).click(function() {
                    var mailLink = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Email', 'Click', mailLink]);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: If this question has been answered, don't forget to mark it as such :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for "mailto:" *within* the else-if for links beginning with "http". The entire if-else-if should be re-written with "mailto:" as a "first class" condition instead of a sub condition of "http:".

Comment: This makes sense. Things were just out of context. Thanks for the speedy reply.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code

```
else if (href_lower.substr(0, 4) == "http")
```

only when this is true will the mailto condition even have a chance to run but when that is true the mailto condition will always be false since mailto syntax does not start with "http"

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com">Send email</a>
```

I think you can probably do something like

```
if(href !== null) { // ....}
else {
    if(href_lower.indexOf('mailto:') !== -1) { // mailto code }
    else { other than mailto code }
}
```